# Trouble linking to gtk/gtk.h even though it's installed

Tags: make, libraries, cmake, pkg-config

I am trying to build CEF (chromiumembedded) on debian jessie

```
##########
Linking CXX static library libcef_dll_wrapper.a
[ 81%] Built target libcef_dll_wrapper
[ 81%] Building CXX object cefclient/CMakeFiles/cefclient.dir/binding_test.cpp.o
In file included from /home/netbrain/tools/cef_binary_3.2171.1979_linux64/cefclient/binding_test.h:9:0,
                 from /home/netbrain/tools/cef_binary_3.2171.1979_linux64/cefclient/binding_test.cpp:5:
/home/netbrain/tools/cef_binary_3.2171.1979_linux64/cefclient/client_handler.h:21:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
cefclient/CMakeFiles/cefclient.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'cefclient/CMakeFiles/cefclient.dir/binding_test.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [cefclient/CMakeFiles/cefclient.dir/binding_test.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:125: recipe for target 'cefclient/CMakeFiles/cefclient.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [cefclient/CMakeFiles/cefclient.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:78: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
##########

##########
find / | egrep ".*gtk/gtk.h$"
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h
##########

##########
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 
##########
```

I'm not very familiar with building from source, alltough as far as i can see I really can't see anything wrong with my system and why CEF wouldn't pick up on this library.

Any ideas on how i can debug this further?

Comment: About a year later i run into the same problem. And found this question a few times but without anyone answering

Answer (score 0):

I used Ubuntu 16.04 and get same error. I switch to **Ninja** build system and it works.

Comment: Happy to hear you found a solution. Could you elaborate any on the steps required?